# meaning of -m in iptables

Tags: iptables

I use the following commands to turn my laptop into a router, that routes traffic from eth0 to wlan0 and vice versa.

```
$ echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Can someone tell me the meaning of -m in the 3rd command? The description from iptables man page says that, -m specifies a match to use. Does that mean "state" is the match? If so, how do I know the value of state? is this a constant of a variable that can be configured? 
Thanks.

Comment: match - see http://bodhizazen.net/Tutorials/iptables or man iptables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `-m` is a flag to indicate a loadable module is about to be implemented.

It will always be immediately followed by the name of the loadable module; in your case, a deprecated module called `state`.  Since the `state` module is deprecated, consider learning and using the module that replaces it called `conntrack`.